# Which verse was Max Cady saying when he was drowning?

Tags: cape-fear-1991

In the ending of **Cape Fear** (1991), when **Sam** handcuffed the legs of **Max Cady** and he started drowning we see him saying something in non-English language and it seemed to me something related to **God**.

[In this clip](https://youtu.be/ctyDL-6f90w) that “strange shouting” starts at 1:21.

As the movie is of neo-noir genre, that ending of **Max Cady** with those “sounds” must be having some hidden meaning in it.

So, what was he saying? And what was the importance of that “saying” at the end of his life?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The non-English part is not in the [script](https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=http://www.cinephiliabeyond.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Cape-Fear-1990-08-31-Draft.compressed.pdf&hl=en) but this is "speaking in tongues".

> Glossolalia or **speaking in tongues** is a phenomenon in which people speak words that are apparently in languages unknown to the speaker. One definition used by linguists is the fluid vocalizing of speech-like syllables that lack any readily comprehended meaning, in some cases as part of **religious practice in which it is believed to be a divine language unknown to the speaker.**
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossolalia)

---

> In the remake, Bowden is able to handcuff Cady's ankle to a railing in the houseboat before it hits submerged rocks and begins to break apart. The two exchange blows with rocks, and Bowden savagely attempts to bring a large rock down on Cady's head. Before he can do so, though, Cady is washed out into the river, still cuffed to part of the houseboat, madly crying out and **speaking in tongues**, and Bowden then watches as Cady is pulled to the bottom of the river and drowns.
>
> [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max_Cady)

---

From the script which does not have this element of speaking in tongues...

> ```
>  Sam watches, bloody and transfixed on the riverbank as Cady -- just his
>  head visible now  -- regresses to the choir boy he once was, long ago. 
>  In a small voice he begins to sing:
>
>      "On Jordan's stormy banks I stand
>       Oh, who will come with me?"
>
>  It's a revival song from Cady's youth, 
>  and he renders it in a reedy, eerie, almost beautiful alto:  
>
>      "I'm bound for the promised land.
>       I'm bound for the promised land."                "
> ```